# Polynomial time for a quadratic equation and linear inequalities?

Tags: computational-complexity, oc.optimization-and-control, operations-research

Does anyone know how to find a feasible solution (or the infeasibility of any solution) in a polynomial time to the following problem:
\begin{align*}
xAx^t = 0, \\
Bx^t = c, \\
x_i \ge 0,
\end{align*}
where A is not definite positive nor definite negative, but it is symmetric.

Comment: Proving there is a polynomial-time solution to this problem will give a proof of P=NP